# How to add my own class inside preloaded-classes which is available in \android\frameworks\base

Tags: android

I am trying to find steps on how to add my own class into preloaded-class?

Please let me know if anyone have tried this.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Do you want to create a custom rom or not? If not then I don't see how to do this.

Comment: I have a jar file which uses some of my own custom classes. Now I need to put this jar file in adroid framework & add my custom classes inside preloaded-classes

Answer (score 6):

You can edit the preloaded-classes file inside the framework.jar at any time.

I do this with patches for a project. Just add it to the list, the preloaded-classes file is simply a text file inside the jar.

For a build, the process is the same, you can add those classes to the list at frameworks/base/preloaded-classes

**Edit:** Since this is my first answer, how about a little documentation...see no less than Diane Hackborn [address this here.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/z-4WkqGvyeY)

Comment: Well done for your first answer and welcome to stack overflow! :)